# openSSL subjectAltNames unclear

Tags: ssl

I'm setting up a webserver is for development and testing purposes, strictly local, no access from the Internet, but needs to be conform the production environment as close as possible, including SSL.
So I have set up a local CA on the server, created a server request using SubjectAltNames for several nodes running on them, and signed it using the just created CA, and instructed apache to user this setup.

CN in both CA as server is tdc.nl - which is the 'domain' I'm using locally. It has sites manage.tdc.nl, www.tdc.nl, so in the server-request, I defined:

```
[ v3-req ] 
...
subjectAltNames = @alt_names
...
[ alt_names ]
DNS.1 = tdc.nl
DNS.2 = manage.tdc.nl
DNS.3 = www.tdc.nl
DNS.4 = mail.tdc.nl
```

All names (except mail.tdc.nl) are registered in \Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts on the workstation that I use to access each of these servers, and in the server itself. I installed the CA certificate on my workstation as trusted base certificate as prompted in many descriptions.

Then I access https://manage.tdc.nl with different browsers.

Chrome signals NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID, Edge signals DLG_FLAGS_SEC_CERT_CN_INVALID. Though both allow me to continue, I want to get on without error messages. However, it's weird that Firefox seems to be happy, even without installing the CA certificate, just accepts the link, and I can proceed without message.

I checked the server certificate and that notes the alternate names, but these are missing in the CA certificate. Should the subjectAlternateNames also be specified in the CA? The documentation I read doesn't show anything on that.

Comment: Do you see the altname in the certificate..

Comment: The request does:

    Attributes: Requested Extensions: 
    ... 
    X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: DNS:tdc.nl, DNS:www.tdc.nl, DNS:manage.tdc.nl, DNS:mail.tdc.nl

but the certificate indeed misses them. So these must have gone missing in the signing process??

Comment: Correct....i am not sure if that is how we mention multiple alternate names , also i will suggest a wildcard certificate instead.

Comment: Ok i now see your answer

Answer (score 0):

Doublechecked config for CA and docs I used: found I was missing

```
copy_extensions = copy
```

Redone signing, now subjectAltNames are in server certificate
After restarting Apache, it worked.